# What is Cloudformation's !Sub equivalent in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to use a variable in Terraform and make a concatenation like I'd do using `!Sub` in Cloudformation.

Something like this..

```
variable "aws_region" {
   default = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "apple" {
   availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
   vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
   cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidr1}"
}
```

How do I do acheive this? `availability_zone = us-west-1a`

Comment: the answer depends on your version of terraform, what version are you using?  what you have should work, what errors are you getting?

Comment: You are interpolating a string correctly there, and the syntax is just like the vast majority of other languages. What are you seeing that makes you believe it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** use interpolation:

```
// addeed from a list
availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}-${var.some_aws_instance_names[count.index]}"
// or static string
availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}-1a"     
// or two local variable   
avilability_zone = "${var.aws_region}-${var.someLocalVariable}"
```

---

**Option 2:** Use `Join` Reference [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html)

If you just want to concatenate !Sub without a separator like "Aws"+"-Instance1A" = "Aws-Instance1A", then:

> ```
> join("", ["Aws", "-Instance1A"])
> ```

Aws-Instance1A

> ```
> join(", ", ["foo", "bar", "choco", "late"])
> ```

foo, bar, choco, late

> ```
> join(", ", ["foo"])
> ```

foo